# In Typescript, how to declare that an export of some name/type is mandatory for a (group of) file(s)?

Tags: typescript, module, export

I have a group of files that I want to all have the same mandatory export of a specific name and type (e.g. all files must have `export const elem: Element = ...`). Is there a way to annotate such thing in Typescript? I looked into d.ts declaration files, but they don't seem to do the trick.

Comment: It would need something like an interface for modules? I don't think this exists, to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, like an interface for modules, exactly. I also think it doesn't exist, just wanted to make sure.